# clojure: how to get several items by index out of vector

Tags: clojure

I am using the following code to extract data by index of [1 2], is there any shorter solution?

```
(vec (map #(nth ["a" "b" "c"] % ) [1 2]))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want *ONLY* the first and second index of a vector, there are many ways...

A simple [sub vector](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/subvec) can be used to persist the first index until the third index.

```
(subvec ["a" "b" "c"] 1 3)
```

You can [map the vector](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv) and apply your vector to the first and second index to return the last two indices as a vector.

```
(mapv ["a" "b" "c"] [1 2])
```

Using the [thread-last](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro, you can take 3 indices and drop the first.

```
(->> ["a" "b" "c"] (take 3) (drop 1))
```

If you have a vector defined with n indices, and all you need is the last n indices, drop base 0 to return the last n.

```
(drop 1 ["a" "b" "c"])
```

Answer (score 9):

`mapv` maps into a vector, and vectors when applied as functions do index lookup

```
(mapv ["a" "b" "c"] [1 2])
```